# contact form edit fields

Tags: magento-1.9, forms, contact-form

Hi Guys I'm new to Magento,

I'm trying to edit a contact form previously developed by another company and cannot seem to find the code anywhere please advise.

I have checked the static blocks to no avail, also checked the `form.phtml` files in the theme. I just need to add a new branch?

This is the form:
https://www.arb.co.za/enquiry

need to make an edit here:

[image]

Thanks

Comment: First of all identify which phtml file is called here using "template Path Hints" options available into magento admin. Then check code into that file. So you get some idea where to make changes.

Comment: Thanks I found it I need to start studying Magento real heard now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like mentioned in the comments...

Use the "**Template Path Hints**" feature to find the right `.phtml` file.

To turn on template path hints in Magento:

1. Log into the magento back-end admin
2. Go to System -> Configuration in the main menu
3. Go to Developer on the bottom left under ADVANCED
4. Switch to the store view on the top left to your current website or store view.
5. Under the Debug tab of the same Developer config page you will see a new option appear that will allow you to turn on/off template path hints.
6. Add your IP to the whitelist at the top of this section to prevent customers from viewing your site like this.

Comment: Excellent answer +1